Easy node module experimentation on backend
I have seen lots of questions regarding this, but the answers don't seem to provide a complete picture.
I have a modern vue3 application which uses a graphql backend.  I'm using vscode.  I want to easily test my endpoints without doing any funky browser/frontend development.  In my project root, I created a folder called api_test.

I plan to manually test by running the root.js file in the node repl in the terminal coupled to vscode.  I execute it like this:
PS M:\source\AdvancedStorageSite> node ./api_test/root.js

My root.js file looks like this:
//root.js

// import {queries} from import('../src/graphql/custom-queries')
// let {queries} = await import('../src/graphql/custom-queries')
// let queries = require('../src/graphql/custom-queries')

console.log(queries)

I have 3 different strategies I'm trying to import my modules.  My modules use imports in them.  This seems important because I have found other SO answers that seem to break based on the import chain.  Here is the result I get with each strategy:
// code
import {queries} from import('../src/graphql/custom-queries')
console.log(queries)

// output
M:\source\AdvancedStorageSite\api_test\root.js:1
let {queries} = await import('../src/graphql/custom-queries')
                ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

// code
let {queries} = await import('../src/graphql/custom-queries')
console.log(queries)

// output
M:\source\AdvancedStorageSite\api_test\root.js:1
let {queries} = await import('../src/graphql/custom-queries')
                ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

// code
let queries = require('../src/graphql/custom-queries')
console.log(queries)

// output
M:\source\AdvancedStorageSite\src\graphql\custom-queries.js:1
export const listLeasesFull = /* GraphQL */ `
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Extra info:
I do a lot more backend development with python, in which case it is easy to immediately highlight a section of code and run it to test it.  I want to find the fastest/most efficient way to test client side logic (written in js), which I can then copy and paste to my front end.  If there is a faster way to write logic and test it against an API than this, I am open to that solution as well.
UPDATE
@JaredSmith
Thanks for the feedback.  Here is an example of how it works in python.

I write a small amount of code on the left, and press ctrl + enter to immediately run the code in the repl on the right.  Works pretty much exactly like it works in the server.  No unittests, frameworks, DOM, etc.  Just a small amount of code. That's all I want to test.  But, it has to work exactly like it would if just copied and pasted it to the production code on the client side.

...I get that this is an unfamiliar stack, but this question seems... really off? First, almost all unit testing of client side logic is done in node.js with a node DOM implementation like jsdom rather than a browser. Secondly, you mention running tests in the node.js repl? Why would you fire up a repl to run tests? Why not use vitest (since you say it's a vue app)? Or failing that jest/mocha/jasmine/any-other-js-test-runner? You go on to mention "running code in Python to test it". Do you mean manual testing? I can't even tell what your question is?

I'm serious: I've written client side JS for over 10 years, Python services for 8, node.js services for 7, using a variety of different tools, frameworks, and IDEs, and I can't even tell what you're trying to do. Maybe include a specific example of what you want rather than trying to describe it in prose? Forget about the import errors for a minute, a better first step might be clearly communicating what you want to see if your whole approach is off.

Running code in a repl is different than “running tests”, it seems like you’re talking about the former?

@DaveNewton - I disagree that "running tests" is universally understood as "unit testing".   I am indeed talking about the former.   Just experimenting with code and getting positive results for my algorithms before I move them to production.

I suppose given the confusions its already caused, I should change the title of the question.

@JamieMarshall I’d just omit the word “test” and only talk about REPL. The JS story is less pleasant than Python/Ruby/Lisp IMO—for JS exploring I’m generally in the REPL for quick hits only, more often I’ll run a file or debug in e.g., IntelliJ.

It seems your problem is that /api_test/root.js is not executed as an ES module. How are you running your other js code? Please post your package.json.

Alright, semantic arguments about what "running tests" means aside, as for your actual question, your issue is that Javascript for complicated historical reasons has several different incompatible module systems. and it kills the repl experience. You will not really be able to replicate your Python workflow: you can't use an import statement inside the repl only the dynamic import function, but if you import a file that uses an import statement to get a dep BOOM! The node.js repl is

...not very useful for what you want, which is really a shame. I recommend that you write a lightweight test harness script to do this kind of ad hoc testing of your code. Or use TDD which completely sidesteps the question. Or something along those lines.
